# Typescript how to mix dynamic([key: type]: type) and static typing for an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

#### Main issue

Not really sure if this is possible, but since i abhor Typescript and it is making my coding hard I figured I'd ask just to make sure.

```
interface ISomeInterface {
  handler: () => {}
  [key: string]: string
}
```

Problem obviously is, the `handler` is a `() => {}` and not a string, so typescript throws an error. Is it possible to somehow make this work?

#### Addendum:

While on the topic, this interface is suppose to be consumed by a `React.Context` and since a requirement of a default value by `React.createContext(/* requires default here */)`, I need to give it a object that matches that interface. When I attempt to pass an object litteral as such:

```
React.createContext({handler: () => {throw new Error('using default context')}})
```

Typescript is making a ruckus by saying `{handler: () => never} cannot be assigned to {handler: () => {}}` any way to make this interface plausible? I tried to make interface implement `() => any`, still didn't work, it wants explicit `never`.

#### Edit #1:

So i've made some changes, namely:

```
interface IFormContext {
  $handleChange: (key?, val?) => void
  $registerField: (key?) => void
  [key: string]: { value: string } | ((key?, val?) => void)
}
```

But now when I am trying to access the field like this: `const {[key]: { value }} = props` which is basically de-structuring with a dynamic key, i get the following error:

> `Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ value: string; } | ((key?: any, val?: any) => void)'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately your named properties must match the [index signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures). 
In this case, since at least one property is a function,  you can use:

`[key: string]: string  | Function;`

or

`[key: string]: any;`

Both should work.

For your addendum, `() => {}` means a function with no arguments that returns a empty object, while the function `() => {throw new Error('using default context')}` is returning nothing, thus the error. 
There is a little bit of confusion with the braces used in types and in the actual function implementation.

A function with the type `() => {}` is actually something like `() => {return {}}` or `() => ({})`.

For a function that returns nothing you can use [never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) or [void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never), but if your handler *may* return something, you can use something like `handler: () => void | boolean`, replacing boolean by the type it may return.

Comment: Okay the whole `() => {}` being `() => ({})` is really Fed up! But fixing that solved pretty much everything

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at the **Edit #1**

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. Maybe you are misplacing destructuring with type assignment. The sintax of `const {[key]: { value }} = props ` is wrong, ` {[key]: { value }} ` is a type, and you should have sent a property name, like in vanilla javascript. If props implements the interface IFormContext, and you want to get a property of it, the sintax is `const {propertyName} = props`, given that props is already defined of an instance of IFormContext, otherwise `const {propertyName} = props as IFormContext` should work too. I hope this helps; :)

Comment: Yeh you did misunderstand that, the `const {[key]: {value}} = props` roughly translates to `const myKeyValue = props['myKeyValue'].value` as destructuring is possible with dynamic keys. Problem is, the `props['myKeyValue'].value` is suppose to reference an object from this interface, and as the interface is defined to expect `{value: string}` this should work.... but it doesn't, because the `| Function` part of the interface's `[key:string]:` obviously cannot get the `.value` of it, hope you get what I said now.

Comment: The quoted error up above, regardless of anything around it, does not make much sense to me, **Property value does not exist on {value: string} | whatever**... I mean it goddamn does! What gives? o.0

Comment: @Dellirium `['value']` exist on `{value: string}` but cannot be guaranteed to exist on the union with what you call **whatever** as that alternative is `(key?: any, val?: any) => void` where `['value']` does not exist.