# Typescript: Defining an interface with both dynamic and static keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Im working with data that looks like

```
{
 8533864186048: "4",
 8533864218816: "1",
 isExchange: true,
 returnType: "exchange",
}
```

where the first two keys are dynamic but will always be strings

so I tried to define the interface as such:

```
interface ReturnData {
  [key: string]: string; <- Applying this to whole interface for some reason
  isExchange?: boolean;
  returnType?: ReturnType;
  selectedVariant: Variant;
}
```

So am having the issue where trying to define a dynamic member on the interface causes ts to try and assign all the other members to type `string`

What would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript how to mix dynamic(\[key: type\]: type) and static typing for an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091272/typescript-how-to-mix-dynamickey-type-type-and-static-typing-for-an-interf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your interface like this

```
interface ReturnData {
    isExchange?: boolean;
    returnType?: ReturnType;
    selectedVariant: Variant;
    [key: string]: string | boolean | ReturnType | Variant;
}
```

Another approach is this if you only want numbered keys to be a string

```
type ReturnData = {
    [key in string | number]: key extends number ? string : string | boolean | ReturnType | Variant;
} & {
    isExchange?: boolean;
    returnType?: RT;
    selectedVariant: V;
};

const k: ReturnData = {
    8533864186048: "4",
    8533864186049: "3",
    8533864186048: true // invalid
};
```

Final Implementation will look like this

```
type ValidKeys = "isExchange" | "returnType" | "selectedVariant";

type ReturnData = {
    [key in string | number]: key extends ValidKeys ? string | boolean | ReturnType | Variant : string;
} & {
    isExchange?: boolean;
    returnType?: ReturnType;
    selectedVariant: Variant;
};
```

Comment: Is there no way to limit additional keys to just being of string type?

Comment: try the latest updated version.  It should work

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
interface ReturnData {
  isExchange?: boolean;
  returnType?: ReturnType;
  selectedVariant: Variant;
  [key: string]: string | boolean | ReturnType | Variant;
}
```

But instead of mixing dynamic and static property together, I think you should refactor your interface like this:

```
interface ReturnData {
  isExchange?: boolean;
  returnType?: ReturnType;
  selectedVariant: Variant;
  someProps: {
    [key: string]: string;
  }
}
```

so the interface is more readable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to people with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can just restrict all `number` keys to be a string: `[key:number]: string`

```js
type CustomReturnType = string;
type Variant = string;

interface ReturnData {
  [key: number]: string; // <--- any number key should be a string
  isExchange?: boolean;
  returnType?: CustomReturnType;
  selectedVariant: Variant;
}

const data: ReturnData = {
  isExchange: true,
  returnType: 'hello',
  selectedVariant: 'variant',
  2334234234: 'sd',
  234234234:23 // expected error
}
```